# Rails: Factories and Associations in Functional Tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, functional-testing, factories

I'm trying to figure out why this doesn't work.

Let's say you three models, User, Foo and Bar. In order for a bar to be created the user must first create and validate a foo object.

```
Class User #snip!
has_many :foos
has_many :bars

Class Foo #snip!
belongs_to :user
has_many :bars

Class Bar #snip!
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :foo
```

I'm trying to get a functional test working where if the user tries to make a new Bar without having a valid foo, they get redirected to the "new" action for a Foo.

I haven't had any problem with the redirect scenario. However, when I try to setup a user with a valid Foo object and try to get the "new" action for a Bar, it still gets redirected to the "new" action of the Foo controller. It still doesn't acknowledge that the User has a Foo.

Here's my controller:

```
 class BarsControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  setup :activate_authlogic
  def setup
    @request.env['HTTPS'] = nil
    @user = Factory.build(:user)
    @foo = Factory.build(:foo, :user => @user)
  end
   test "should get new when user has a valid foo" do
     @request.env['HTTPS'] = 'on'
     UserSession.create(@user)
     get :new
     assert_response :success
  end
```

This is the redirect function I have in my application controller which is called in my bar controller:

```
  def foo_required
    if current_user && @current_user.foos.valid.empty? && @current_user.foos.empty?
    flash[:notice] = "You must have a verified foo in order to create a Bar!"
    redirect_to new_foo_path
    elsif current_user && @current_user.foos.valid.empty?
    flash[:notice] = "You must verify your foos in order to create a Bar!"
    redirect_to foos_path
    end
 end
```

Here's the Foo Factory:

```
Factory.define :foo do |f|
   #attributes
   f.valid true
   f.association :user
end
```

Instead I get redirected to "https://test.host:80/foos/new" The controller doesn't acknowledge that the user has a Foo...

The session is valid so this seems like a factory problem, but I'm not sure what it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming that this is factory_girl. You are calling `Factory.build` which doesn't save anything to the database, so you never have the foreign key value needed for your association. Switch those to `Factory.create` and you should see a difference.

Comment: Of course it had to be something simple like that! *hits head* Thanks a lot jdl, you saved me a day of hair-pulling!